# django 2.1.7 installation failed on python 3.4

Tags: linux, installation, django

> Downloading Django-2.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB): 4.3MB downloaded
>
> Downloading/unpacking Django Requirement already up-to-date: pytz in
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages (from Django) Installing
>   collected packages: Django
>   *** Error compiling '/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/contrib/admin/actions.py'...
>   File "/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/contrib/admin/actions.py",
>   line 55
>       **modeladmin.admin_site.each_context(request),
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> *** Error compiling '/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/contrib/admin/checks.py'...
>   File "/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/contrib/admin/checks.py",
>   line 73
>       *self._check_autocomplete_fields(admin_obj),
>                  ^ SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
>
> .....
>
> *** Error compiling '/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/feedgenerator.py'...
>   File "/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/feedgenerator.py",
>   line 82
>       **kwargs,
>        ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> *** Error compiling '/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/functional.py'...   File
>   "/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/functional.py", line 12
>       return _curried_func(*args, *moreargs, **{**kwargs, **morekwargs})
>                                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> *** Error compiling '/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/log.py'...   File
>   "/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/log.py", line 229
>       )
>       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> *** Error compiling '/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/tree.py'...   File
>   "/tmp/pip-build-tj2qptrw/Django/django/utils/tree.py", line 76
>       return hash((self.**class**, self.connector, self.negated, *make_hashable(self.children)))
>                                                                         ^ SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
>
> Successfully installed Django Cleaning up...

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin
```

Running **django-admin** or **python3 manage.py** (Python 3.4.2, tried with and without virtualenv, same output)

```
(ve) user@localhost:$ django-admin

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/user/.local/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.conf import settings
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.utils.functional import LazyObject, empty
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 12
    return _curried_func(*args, *moreargs, **{**kwargs, **morekwargs})
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is a basic version mismatch problem (python vs django), that can be fixed, in this case:

```
 python3 -m pip install Django==2.0 --user
```

we have to respect the version [requirements](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/faq/install/) 
Django version -> Python versions 
1.11 -> 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 (added in 1.11.17) 
2.0 -> 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 
2.1, 2.2 -> 3.5, 3.6, 3.7